# Test Class - How to create a Partner Account

Tags: apex, unit-test, class, partner-communities

My need would be to create a Partner Account **(that is: an Account with field isPartner set to true!)** in test class, having checkbox PartnerAccount set to true, but I'm not having success with this requirement..and my debug code returns "false". Any suggestions?

```
Account acc= new Account(Name='Partner Account');
    insert acc;     
    Contact con = new Contact (LastName='TestContact', AccountId=acc.Id); 
    insert con;     

    Profile p2 = [SELECT Id From Profile where Name='ETH Partner Community User'];


    User u2 = new User(
    Alias = 'newUser',
    IsActive = true,
    Email='newuser2@testorg.com', 
    EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
    LastName='Testing',
    LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
    LocaleSidKey='en_US',
    ProfileId = p2.Id, 
    TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles',
    UserName='newuser2@testorg.com',
    ContactId = con.Id);

    insert u2;
    system.debug('@@' + u2.Contact.Account.isPartner);
```

Comment: Your code makes it appear as though you're trying to create a partner community user. To do that, the contact needs to be related to a partner account. You first need to create the account and convert the account to a partner. Right now, you're trying to apply a partner profile to a contact that's related to a non partner account.

Comment: So my question is : how to make the Account become Partner by code?

Comment: It depends on the kind of partner account you want. See the [Object Reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/object_reference.pdf) for more on Accounts, AccountPartner, OpportuntyPartner, Partner, PartnerRole and other objects like Contact and User that might be relevant to your issue.

Comment: I need only that the Account has the isPartner (standard field) checkbox set to "true". This is a class test for a trigger that performs action on this checkbox value basis

Comment: If you think that's all you need, then try setting it to true and updating the account in your test class.

Comment: It is a read only field..

Comment: Then perhaps it would behoove you to take the time to read the documentation on how partner accounts are created in the Object Reference I've previously referred you to!

Comment: Why do you down vote my question?  Also,  your answer is not helpful..!

Comment: @ToninoTripodi I also have also faced this same difficulty more than once now, and the documentation says nothing about it. I have tried toying around with the values of `Account.Type`, which accepts a "Partner" value, but to no success.
If you have any updates on this, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation the `isPartner` field:

> Indicates whether the account has at least one contact enabled to use
>   the organization's partner portal (true) or not (false).

So if you create the user correctly then associate them with an account you will be good to go:

**Create User** - Passing in the contact ID

```
Account a = new Account();
insert a;
Contact c = New Contact(LastName = 'Test', AccountID = a.id);
insert c;
User newUser = createPartnerUser(c.id);

private static user createPartnerUser(ID cId){
    Profile p = [Select ID, Name from Profile Where Name = 'YOUR PARTNER PROFILE NAME'];

    user u = New User(
        UserName = 'test_' + math.random() + '@test.com',
        FirstName = 'Test-First',
        LastName = 'Test-Last',
        Alias = 'test',
        email = 'test' + math.random() + '@test.com',
        CommunityNickName = string.valueOf(math.random()).substring(0,6),
        ProfileID = p.id,
        TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/New_York', 
        LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', 
        EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8', 
        LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
        ContactID = cId

        );

    insert u;

    return u;


}

a = [Select isPartner From Account where ID = :a.id];
system.assert(a.isPartner,'Is Partner flag was not set to true');
```

Modify per your needs

Answer (score 0):

After creating first user with profile equals to 'Partner Community User', and linking this user contact to account, IsPartner field will turn to true automatic

Answer (score 0):

You can set IsPartner in a second update. You can't set it on creation of the account but after it's inserted you can.

Account a = new Account('My account'); 
insert a;
a.IsPartner = true; 
update a;

I've had issues where if I don't do this and rely on the contact being a partner user the account will have IsPartner set to true but trying to assign it to records that require a partner account fails. For example trying to set the PartnerId on PartnerFundAllocation will fail unless you explicitly update IsPartner to true.